# How to position ":before" element used as icon in zurb foundation's Side nav?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I added a sub-menu to foundation's side nav exactly like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979315/how-to-add-submenu-to-zurb-foundation-side-nav) example, but the icon is above the text.

My CSS:

```
.hasChildren:before{
    content: "\25ba";
    float: left
}
.hasChildren.active:before{
    content: "\25bc";
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="large-4 medium-4 columns menu-wrapper">
    <div class="panel">
        <h4>Menu</h4>
        <ul class="side-nav">
             <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Link drop</a>
                 <ul class="side-nav">
                     <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.side-nav li:has("ul")').children('ul').hide(); //hide submenu
$('.side-nav li:has("ul")').addClass('hasChildren'); // add class to li ul child
$('.side-nav li:has("ul")').click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass( "active" ) // add active class to clicked menu item
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(); //toggle submenu
});
```

[Image describing my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nIud.png)

[My problem on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/remix2000/vpoycbzb/#base)

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use relative positioning, like this:

```css
.hasChildren:before{
    content: "\25ba";
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
}
.hasChildren.active:before{
    content: "\25bc";
}
```

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vpoycbzb/1/